# Java - Generate random number but exclude few ranges in between

Tags: java

I want to generate random number say between 1 to 100, but want to exclude ranges from 20 to 30 and 50-70.

Comment: What have you tried and what isn't working as expected?

Comment: Try to write a custom method, there's no such utility in Java. Also, please try to mention while asking question on what are you trying in code or just asking the idea/approach.

Comment: `Random r = new Random(); int v = new int [] {r.nextInt(1,20), r.nextInt(30,50), r.nextInt(70,100)}[r.nextInt(0,3)];`Note that ranges int java are specified and thus presumed to be inclusive to exclusive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Random random = new Random();
final int AMOUNT_OF_RANGES = 3;
int num;
int range;

range = random.nextInt(AMOUNT_OF_RANGES) + 1;
switch (range){
    case 1 -> num = random.nextInt(1, 21);
    case 2 -> num = random.nextInt(30, 51);
    case 3 -> num = random.nextInt(70, 101);
}
```

I took a range [1,20] and [30, 50] and [70, 100] as an example but actually u can add as many as u want. Make sure to add extra one to max digit to include it.Usually it works like [1, 20), so keep it in mind. Syntax is

```
random.nextInt(startOfRange, endOfRange);
```

Comment: So what we're doing here is randomly selecting ranges in which we want our number,  then selecting a random number from that range. That's very good actually.

Answer (score 1):

The ranges are not same so using a selector like `r.nextInt(0,3)` to decide which range to use would be inbalanced, in favour of the short ranges over bigger 70-100.

Instead use one range and adjust with if statement something like (not near a PC to test):

```
Random r = new Random(); 

int x = r.nextInt(1,69);
if ( x >= 39) 
    return x + 32;
else if ( x >= 20)
    return x + 11;
else return x;
```

This should handle 1..19, 31..49 and 71..100, but you may need to adjust if 30/70 are needed.

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun you can create an Interface that returns an `IntSupplier` to generate a random number in any number of ranges.  This is related to my earlier comment where an array's cell with a random number is referenced. This is better in that the value is not generated until after the `IntSupplier` is chosen and invoked.

First the interface contains a predefined Random instance and a static method which takes an array of ranges. The arrays of `IntSuppliers` for each individual range is created using a stream.  The supplier to use is indexed from `0 to the number of ranges` provided.`

```
interface RandomGenerator {
    
    final Random r = new Random();
    public static IntSupplier forRanges(int[][] v) {
        IntSupplier[] sups = Arrays.stream(v)
                .<IntSupplier>map(
                        range -> () -> r.nextInt(range[0], range[1]))
                .toArray(IntSupplier[]::new);
        return () -> sups[r.nextInt(0, sups.length)].getAsInt();
    }
}
```

Generate a supplier and display some values. I am using extremely limited ranges to facilitate visual verification.

```
IntSupplier rnd = RandomGenerator.forRanges(
                new int[][] { { 1, 3 }, { 31,33 }, { 91,93 } });
    
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    System.out.println(rnd.getAsInt());
}
```

prints something like the following:

```
31
1
91
1
2
32
31
2
2
31
```

At first glance, the statement `return () -> sups[r.nextInt(0, sups.length)].getAsInt();` may appear confusing.  What is happening is that the index to the supplier array `sup` is called to get the appropriate `IntSupplier` for the chosen range. Then that supplier's `getAsInt` is called to get the random number. What is returned is yet another `IntSupplier` which also has that number.  It could look something like `()-> 2`.  So when `rnd.getAsInt` is called, it returns `2`.

This ensures that each invocation by `rnd.getAsInt()` will return a random number from a random range.